# Django ListView with post method, get_queryset does not come filtered

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

In my application i made a `ListView`, in this `ListView` I have to make a post so I'm defining the post method, in this post method i need the filtered `get_queryset` method, but it comes unfiltered as if it is default.

I made some research and I've noticed method `post()` is ran before `get_queryset()`, my question is: Is there any way I can get the filtered `get_queryset()` in the `post()` method?

Ex:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(FilteredListView, self).get_queryset()
    q = Q()
    if self.request.session.get('make_id'):
        q.add(Q(owner__make=self.request.session['auto_id']), Q.AND)

    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs.filter(q).distinct('id').order_by('-id')
    return qs.filter(q, owner=self.request.user.company).distinct('id').order_by('-id')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'action' in self.request.POST:
        action = self.request.POST.get('action')
        if action == 'batch_approve':

            queryset = self.get_queryset() # i need the filtered queryset here, but it comes unfiltered               

            return redirect('{}?{}'.format(reverse('flow:filtered_list'), request.GET.urlencode()))
    return redirect('flow:filtered_list')
```

Comment: Exactly where do you *use* the queryset here? You seem to redirect to somewhere, and thus likely the target page does not filter this correctly? Note that the parameters in the post request are in `request.POST`, not `request.GET`

Comment: This is a ListView and i am redirecting back to it when post is finished

Comment: In my database i have 4 objects, but if it comes filtered it should come 1, the get_queryset works in the listview, but it isn't processed in the post method, because get_queryset is ran before post, so it's coming as default queryset

Comment: but once the redirection is made, the `request.POST` data is "gone", since that is a new GET request.

Comment: i think you got it wrong, this is the flow: i access the page, the queryset comes filtered from overriding get_queryset(), i make the post, in the post i want to access the filtered queryset, but it comes as default(unfiltered) queryset, because post() method is ran before get_queryset() in the ListView Flowchart, i guess it should be filtered, but i don't understand why it's coming as if it was .all()

Comment: No, as Williem says you are not using the queryset before you redirect. You call `get_queryset`, but then immediately return a redirect.

Comment: Actually, i figured it out. My mistake was i didn't tell you i was using django-filter. I had to use django-filter "filter_queryset" method to get get_queryset filtered.